# How to plot subset of pandas.DataFrame with Plotly

Tags: plotly

I got pandas.DataFrame df:

Open     High      Low    Close         Volume  index  DayTime  setup

0    107.390  107.402  107.389  107.402     190.099998      0      0.0     -1

1    107.190  107.275  107.187  107.265    1419.299994      1      1.0     1

2    107.272  107.272  107.255  107.256     174.000000      2      2.0     -1

3    107.255  107.255  107.185  107.255    2581.300001      3      3.0     -1

4    107.199  107.258  107.185  107.245    4102.199995      4      4.0     -1

5    107.195  107.258  107.185  107.250    3335.600000      5      5.0     1

6    107.242  107.258  107.185  107.248    2824.900019      6      6.0     -1

7    107.343  107.345  107.187  107.245    1291.600012      7      7.0     -1

8    107.195  107.265  107.180  107.251    2746.099976      8      8.0     1

then I select subset from the dataframe:

dfs = df.loc[df['setup'] == 1]

when I try to draw plot with Plotly and dfs, it shows error, but it works with df.

fig = FF.create_candlestick(dfs['Open'], dfs['High'], dfs['Low'], dfs['Close'], dates=dfs['index'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Qiu/Desktop/FX Programming/H1Signals.py", line 102, in 
    fig = FF.create_candlestick(dfs['Open'], dfs['High'], dfs['Low'], dfs['Close'], dates=dfs['index'])
  File "C:\Users\Qiu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 5810, in create_candlestick
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Qiu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 4973, in _validate_ohlc
    if high[index] < lst[index]:
  File "C:\Users\Qiu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 583, in **getitem**
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\Qiu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1980, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 103, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3332)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3035)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 303, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6610)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6554)
KeyError: 0

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
dfs = df.loc[df['setup'] == 1]
dfs = dfs.reset_index()
fig = FF.create_candlestick(dfs['Open'], dfs['High'], dfs['Low'], dfs['Close'], dates=dfs['index'])
```

When you use your condition selection to splice the dataframe it keeps its original index. Plotly backend code tries to go through the index in a linear fashion so this can break. However, this may add a column named 'index' or 'unnamed: 0'. So make sure you don't have two columns named 'index' before you plot. Hope this helps.